# NoSuchMethodError: freemarker.template.Configuration

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jar, freemarker

Why is this error happening?
I'm using freemarker-2.3.20 and spring-webmvc-3.2.17

```
 Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: freemarker.template.Configuration.<init>(Lfreemarker/template/Version;)V
        at org.springframework.ui.freemarker.FreeMarkerConfigurationFactory.newConfiguration(FreeMarkerConfigurationFactory.java:320)
        at org.springframework.ui.freemarker.FreeMarkerConfigurationFactory.createConfiguration(FreeMarkerConfigurationFactory.java:250)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.freemarker.FreeMarkerConfigurer.afterPropertiesSet(FreeMarkerConfigurer.java:114)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1637)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1574)
        ... 58 more
```

Comment: Thsi error appears when calling a method on an object in a library, you are most likely using separate versions of the library when compiling and running.  could you post your pom.xml?

Comment: Our application not using pom.xml, Instead of it adding dependencies using .classpath.xml

Comment: could you post version of all freemarker jars?

Comment: as I said , Only freemarker-2.3.20.jar is using

Answer (score 4):

According to [maven dependency](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-webmvc/3.2.17.RELEASE), `spring-webmvc-3.2.17` compiled with the version `2.3.20` of `freemarker`. So you you have to use this version to ommit conflicts.

**Updated** : link updated

It seems to me that `FreeMarkerConfigurationFactory` looks for a `Configuration` constructor with the `version` parameter, this has been added in the version `2.3.21` of freemarker. I think the spring version you mentioned is not good. Your are probably used a version greater than `4.1.5.RELEASE`.

Comment: But this link says something else, Confused  https://www.versioneye.com/java/org.springframework:spring-webmvc/3.2.17.RELEASE

Comment: You're right I shared a bad link

Comment: @zeji see updated answer.

Comment: Just use the latest stable version anyway (2.3.25-incubating at the moment). That can save time for you because of FreeMarker's improvements alone.